# How to create xpath locator when element does not have any attributes

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, ui-automation

How can I access the element using xpath selector if that particular element does not have any attributes?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<challenge-details-card>
   <div class="card-body card-content-container">
      <div>
         <h1 class="card-title text-clr-tertiary">Custom Name</h1>
         <hr class="border-clr-gainsboro" />
         <h3 class="card-info text-clr-tertiary">
            <span translate="Challenges.ChallengeRuns" ng-reflect-translate="Challenges.ChallengeRu">Challenge runs:</span>
            July 15 - July 27
            <!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"}-->
            <span>
               (12 days
               <span translate="Genesis.GlobalLabels.Left" ng-reflect-translate="Genesis.GlobalLabels.Left">Left</span>
               !)
            </span>
         </h3>
         <p class="card-copy">Custom Text</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card-footer background-clr-light-gray">
      <a translate="Genesis.Challenges.ViewChallengeRules" ng-reflect-translate="Genesis.Challenges.ViewChallen">View Challenge Rules</a>
   </div>
</challenge-details-card>
```

http://prntscr.com/ofnudx

I am trying to create an xpath to get "July 15 - July 27" text.

Comment: Which language bindings are you using? Java / Python, C#?

Answer (score 1):

You can access [innerText()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) property of the [h3 tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) using XPath `text()` operator in conjunction with [contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) function, something like:

```
//h3[contains(text(),'July 15 - July 27')]
```

Demo:

[image]

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Comment: I want to read that specific text which will be dynamic. I need to get what is written there.

Comment: Well, that's a text node so `//h3[contains(text(),'July 15 - July 27')]`, will never work.

Comment: Then go for `//h3[contains(@class,'card-info')]`

Answer (score 0):

The text is present under **h3** tag.

You can try with this **css selector** :

```
h3.card-info.text-clr-tertiary
```

If you want xpath :

```
//h3[contains(@class,'card-info text-clr-tertiary')]
```

You can use `getText()` method to get the text which is present under selenium-Java library.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text **July 15 - July 27** you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *Java* and *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println((String)((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(., 'Challenge runs')]/..")))));
  ```